# HTTP Request Not Mimicking Form Correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, web-scraping

I'm trying to bypass this page http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/ by mimicking the POST data when you click "I Agree". I've been able to do it with PHP but for some reason I can't recreate the request in Python. The response is always the page with the disclaimer despite sending the correct POST data. The title of the page I want to land on is "Maryland Judiciary Case Search Criteria". I'm using Python 3.

```
    url = "http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/"
    postdata = parse.urlencode({'disclaimer':'Y','action':'Continue'})
    postdata = postdata.encode("utf-8")
    header = {"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

    req = request.Request(url,data=postdata,headers=header)
    res = request.urlopen(req)
    print(res.read())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the URL you want to post to is actually `http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/processDisclaimer.jis`. Try this:

```
url = "http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/processDisclaimer.jis"
postdata = parse.urlencode({'disclaimer':'Y','action':'Continue'})
postdata = postdata.encode("utf-8")
header = {"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

req = request.Request(url,data=postdata,headers=header)
res = request.urlopen(req)
print(res.read())
```

Comment: That did it. I wonder why http://casesearch.courts.state.md.us/casesearch/ worked with curl in PHP? Thanks!